# passing a callback function via props to child component is undefined in child vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, callback

I have a Vue component that passes a callback function to another child component via props. However, it is the only piece that is undefined in the child.

I have created a [repo](https://github.com/rpreilley/testRepo) for this so the files can be looked at. In the file brDialog.vue, I am passing button to the function click(), which should have access to the buttons callback that was passed within props from App.vue, however it is undefined within brDialog while the other two things passed with it are present(label and data).

I'll post the brDialog file, and will post the others if needed, but figured it would be easier to link a repo than post all the different files. I'm a bit new to Vue, so possibly something I'm missing in the documentation.

If you run the repo and click the Form Test button in the header, this is where the issue is.

brDialog.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-dialog
          v-model="show"
          width="500"
          persistent
          >
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title> {{ title }} </v-card-title>
            <slot name="content"></slot>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn
                v-for="button in buttons"
                :key="button.label"
                small
                @click.native="click(button)"
              >
                {{ button.label }}
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                v-if="showCloseButton"
                small
                @click.native="closeDialog()"
              >
                {{ closeButtonLabel }}
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { props } from './props.js'

export default {
  name: 'brForm',
  components: {
    brTextField: () => import('@/controls/brTextField/brTextField.vue'),
    brTextArea: () => import('@/controls/brTextArea/brTextArea.vue'),
    brSelectList: () => import('@/controls/brSelectList/brSelectList.vue')
  },
  props: props,
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    async click (button) {
      const response = await button.callback(button.data)

      if (response.close) {
        this.closeDialog()
      }
    },
    closeDialog () {
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  },
  computed: {

  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Maybe this is something I'm missing with an $emit in Vue or something, but it seems it should be working. Can someone point out why the callback is undefined after being passed to brDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callback` is undefined because you define your `data` property (App.vue from your repo) with an arrow function and loose the Vue context on `this`:

```
data: () => {
  return {
    testingForm: {
      //...
      dialog: {
        props: {
          buttonCallback: this.testingFormSave, //<-- here
          buttons: [
            {
              label: 'Save',
              data: {},
              callback: this.testingFormSave //<-- and here
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

To fix your issue, change `data: () => {...}` to `data () {...}`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the second pair of eyes! Works like a charm. I figured it would be something small. I have marked your answer correct.